# Python SMTP - [Errno 101] Network is unreachable on AWS EC2

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp

I am trying to verify the email address of the user.

When trying to connect to the user's host using MX record I always get a 'Network is unreachable' error on the AWS EC2 instance. However, it works perfectly fine locally.

```
records = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX')
mx_record = records[0].exchange
mx = str(mx_record)
smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP(host=mx)
```

If I try to use:

```
smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host=mx, port=465)
```

I get the same issue.

Please share any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work probably [because](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/):

> **AWS blocks outbound traffic on port 25 (SMTP) of all EC2 instances and Lambda** functions by default. If you want to send outbound traffic on port 25, you can request for this restriction to be removed.

Although not explicitly stated I would say it is same for 465.

As explained in the link, you have to contact AWS support to remove this restriction, or use [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/).

Comment: Thank you @marcin, this worked perfectly. The request was approved by AWS and after the redeploying everything is working as expected.